# android.os.FileUtils.setPermissions() returns 1 in Android Nougat

Tags: android, security, executable, android-7.0-nougat

I use reflection (find class `android.os.FileUtils`and method `setPermissions()` to mark my file (bundled in app package directory) as executable. It worked before Android Nougat but on N it returns 1:

ZipHelper:

```
Integer result = FileHelper.chmod(outFile, 0755);
if (result == null || result != 0)
     android.util.Log.d("ZipHelper", "chmod failed with error result " + result.intValue());
```

FileHelper:

```
public static void init_chmod() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException {
    fileUtils = Class.forName("android.os.FileUtils");
    setPermissions = fileUtils.getMethod("setPermissions", String.class, int.class, int.class, int.class);
}

public static int chmod(File path, int mode) throws Exception {
    return (Integer) setPermissions.invoke(null, path.getAbsolutePath(), mode, -1, -1);
}
```

In the log:

```
01-19 12:46:39.365    2558-2667/name.myname.android.app D/ZipHelper﹕ chmod failed with error result 1
01-19 12:46:39.390    2558-2667/name.myname.android.app W/FileUtils﹕ Failed to chmod(/storage/emulated/0/app/tutorials/cplusplus.com#1.0#1/compounddatatypes/arrays/multidimensional/source3.cpp): android.system.ErrnoException: chmod failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

My app is targeted to `21` so i don't manage permissions the way it's required for N. The app gets 'Storage' permission automatically and i can see it in app settings in N AVD. I'm testing in emulator.

What return code `1` means?
I suspect it's related with security but i have no idea what should be done (i saw about general permission approach for N but what permission is required in my case expect already granted 'Storage').
What should i do to make it working again?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source for android.os.FileUtils (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/FileUtils.java), the setPermissions method is performing a chmod under the covers, and returning the errno.

1 = EPERM, or "Operation not permitted".

Can you just call setExecutable on the file?

```
File myFile;
myFile.setExecutable(true);
```